# How to find out Code Coverage by using Blanket.js

Tags: code-coverage, qunit, blanket.js

How to find out Code Coverage by using Blanket.js.
In our MVC project I have added Javascript files in this hierarchy:

```
<script src="qunit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="blanket.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But in Code Coverage percantage it's reflecting (NaN %). Can anyone please assist me to fix this issue.